# How do I completely remove MySQL from a 64-bit windows 7 machine?

Tags: mysql

I'm new to MySQL and struggling to find a version and workbench which is stable on my 64 bit Windows 7 machine.

I've decided to attempt to completely remove MySQL from my machine and to restart the installation process from scratch.

However, after uninstalling all software linked with MySQL using the conventional control panel uninstaller, I see there are some MySQL windows services still remaining on my machine.

I can't see any obvious method to remove these services and they have since been causing me difficulties when trying to install different versions of MySQL.

Could anyone please advise how I can remove these services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the command `sc delete [MySQL]` where [MySQL] is the name of the service.